# React.findDOMNode comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<script type="text/jsx">
/* @jsx React.DOM*/
var Login = React.createClass({
    Validate: function(){
        debugger;
        var username = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).trim();
        var password = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).trim();
        console.log('Username: ' + username + '\nPassword: ' + password);
        if(username == 'username' && password == 'password'){
            alert('Success');
        }
        else{
           alert('Failure');
        }
    },
    Clear: function(){

    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                Login 
                <p></p>
                Username: <input type="text" ref="username" /><br />
                Password: <input type="password" ref="password" /><br /><br />
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.Validate} />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="button" value="Clear" onClick={this.Clear} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('wrapper'))
</script>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/gaqs3p17/. I get `TypeError: React.findDOMNode(...).trim is not a function`, which makes sense, since `findDOMNode` returns a DOM element, not a string. It does not return `undefined`. If you mean that `React.findDOMNode` is `undefined`, then you have to upgrade your React version. It was introduced in v0.13 afaik.

Comment: Yes, i was using v0.12.1.  Also React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value works in v0.13

Comment: Yes, adding `.value` works, since `input` elements have a `value` property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`React.findDOMNode` was introduced in React v0.13, so make sure you are using at least v0.13.

Answer (score 6):

In React **v0.13** use `React.findDOMNode()`.

In earlier versions e.g. **v0.12** you can use `component.getDOMNode()`

```
this.refs.myRef.getDOMNode();
```

To support ES6 based patterns going forward, the React team added `React.findDOMNode(component)` to be used in place of component.getDOMNode().

Answer (score 6):

Not sure when it happened, but it seems to live in ReactDOM now `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode.

Answer (score 3):

> React.findDOMNode

has been deprecated, use

> ReactDOM.findDOMNode

in React 15.1 and up

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very relevant for the code mentioned with the question above, however a couple of other checks from react's docs are:

1. ***"When render returns null or false, findDOMNode returns null."***
2. ***"findDOMNode cannot be used on functional components."***

Hope this helps someone in need.